# Using setRotate rescales the imageview

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, imageview, scale

I'm using the following code in order to rotate an imageview :

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate((float) angle,main_needle.getWidth()/2, (float)(main_needle.getHeight()/1.1787));
main_needle.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

The problem is that this code also rescales the imageview . I tried adding the setScale to my code but it didn't help.

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate((float) angle,main_needle.getWidth()/2, (float)(main_needle.getHeight()/1.1787));     
matrix.setScale(main_needle.getWidth(), main_needle.getHeight());
main_needle.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

I updated the code based on the comment to this :

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate((float) angle,main_needle.getWidth()/2, (float)(main_needle.getHeight()/1.1787));
matrix.setScale((int)(main_needle.getWidth()/Math.cos((double)angle)),(int)( main_needle.getHeight()/Math.sin((double)angle)));
main_needle.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);  
main_needle.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

But this code just makes the imageview disapear

The easiest fix I used is to scale down the image in photoshop so that the pixels match the dp for example an image set in xml at 70dp by 100dp should use a drawable 70 by 100 pixel .Thanks everyone for your responces.

Comment: your setScale is wrong. He expects a scale not a fixed size. let's say that the new width (after rotation) is width/cos(angle) and the new height is height/sin(angle) you can  easily calculate the scale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `matrix.postRotate();` And this one is must

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix(); 
main_needle.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
matrix.postRotate((float) i,main_needle.getWidth()/2, (float)(main_needle.getHeight()/1.1787)); 
main_needle.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Actually thats because you try to rotate a view in a linear layout. And this will cause its dedicated space to expand or shrink.

Idea 1: try using a frame layout have and your view rotate inside there Idea 2: try a custom view subclass and draw your turntable in the onDraw. In the internet look for a compass drawing example for start.

Comment: Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate((float) i,main_needle.getWidth()/2, (float)(main_needle.getHeight()/1.1787));
     main_needle.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);  
     main_needle.setImageMatrix(matrix);     Unfortunatelly not working

Comment: the problem remains with or without the imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

Comment: try now:
`Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
main_needle.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX); 
matrix.postRotate((float) i,main_needle.getWidth()/2, (float)(main_needle.getHeight()/1.1787));
main_needle.setImageMatrix(matrix);`

Comment: i have tried all the combinations but the result is that the imageview get rescaled to the actual size of the image in pixels and doesnt follow the dp setting from the xml :(